# How to enable iQuery autocomplete after specific keystrokes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocommplete. I want to run the autocomplete function only when the input has more than 2 digits in it. Following is what I tried:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#postcode').on('input', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();


            if(val.length > 2) {
                $( "#postcode" ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/read_postcode') ?>",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            data: {
                                q: request.term
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

The code runs fine, without error. But the result is not as expected. Also, when I put `alert();` inside the `if()` condition, the result is as expected but not the autocomplete section. What is wrong ?

Update: With this code what happens is, the autocomplete function runs when the fourth digit is entered and then, it runs on every keystroke until the field has zero digits in it.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Why is this question voted to close ?

Comment: I voted to close since telling us only that *"the result is not as expected"* is simply not enough information the answer your question "*what is wrong?"*.  Thanks for updating it with details about what actually happened - this makes the question more clear and useful to others. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `minLength`

> **minLength**: The minimum number of characters a user has to type before the Autocomplete activates. Zero is useful for local data with just a few items. Should be increased when there are a lot of items, where a single character would match a few thousand items.

```
$(function () {
    $("#postcode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/read_postcode') ?>",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/1800/)

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach here is to use autocomplete's `minLength` setting:

```
$( "#postcode" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 2
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

The reason why your initial code is behaving that way is because calling `autocomplete()` actually attaches an event handler to the element.  What you've done here is to wait until more than 2 characters are entered and *then* attached a new event.  Subsequent keystrokes trigger the autocomplete, which is why you are seeing results at 4 characters and thereafter.

This is not the same as firing the autocomplete ajax request at a minimum character length - which is what the `minLength` argument is for.  Hope that helps explain things.